# MeteorJS Image Handling

Tags: image-processing, meteor

Can anyone point me in the right direction for having cropping an image server with Meteor? I've gone across the web and I've read a bit about formidable, filepicker.io, and imagemagick/graphicsmagick. But do these actually work seamlessly if I supply the x,y,height, and width values to the server?

And do they work with Meteor and possibly CollectionFS? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a third party javascript library like [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/crop/) to do a crop and then do whatever you want with the cropped image:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    Pixastic.process(img, "crop", {
        rect : {
            left : 50, top : 50, width : 50, height : 50
        }
    });
}
document.body.appendChild(img);
img.src = "myimage.jpg";
```

Some other options would be [ProcessingJS](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html) or [CamanJS](http://camanjs.com/guides/#AdvancedUsage)

Or you can do it on the server using an [appropriate npm package](https://npmjs.org/search?q=image) (most of which actually wrap imagemagick). You can use the wonderful third party [meteor npm package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/npm) to easily get a reference from the npm packages that you intend to use.

If your workflow allows for it, I'd go for the client side solution to keep it simple and lighter on the server.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll take your advice and keep it on the client. Pixastic looks pretty simple. I'll try that out first. Do you have experience with Pixastic or CamanJS? How reliable/efficient would you say they are?

Comment: I have just very basic experience with Pixastic and have heard of them both previously. Very easy to use. They both have good reviews. They both rely on the canvas element to do image manipulation, just slightly different api's. They have no reason to be unreliable/inefficient on a modern browser. You might need to special-case old IE if you need to support them, though.

Comment: One last thing, I'm not uploading the images myself; users will be. So you do you have any suggestions for implementing an actual image cropping interface that'll register the x,y,height,width values for me so I can save them into the database? Any experience with certain plugins?

Comment: [ImgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) and [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) are kind of well known. There is also a [wrapper around imgareaselect](https://github.com/Andrew8xx8/awesome-cropper) that streamlines the process. You'll need to feed the output (the cropped image) to your uploader, though.